# How do I fix ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

This query:

```
SELECT u2.MR_ID from up_module_master u2 where u2.MR_NAME='Applications'
```

returns two rows but when i created it I created only one row.

```
INSERT INTO UP_PERMISSION_MASTER ( MR_ID,P_NAME,P_HOLDER)
   values ((SELECT u2.MR_ID from up_module_master u2
            where u2.MR_NAME='Applications'),'create','0')
```

How do I fix ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: limit your result to 1

Comment: To be clear, how many records do you want to insert into UP_PERMISSION_MASTER: 1 or 1 for each matching record in UP_MODULE_MASTER?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do `INSERT...SELECT` instead of `INSERT VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO UP_PERMISSION_MASTER ( MR_ID,P_NAME,P_HOLDER)
   SELECT u2.MR_ID, 'create','0'
   from up_module_master u2
   where u2.MR_NAME='Applications'
```